# What is the most streamlined QR Decoder on iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, qr-code

I noticed ZXing, but it seems like it has a bunch of stuff I don't need. I just need to be able to decode QR Codes that have a name, address, and email encoded.

I don't really want the user to have to install an external application i.e. Barcode Reader, and this will be a private application used by a minimal amount of people.

Can someone point me in the direction of a streamlined framework that lets users decode these codes?

Comment: you can take that ZXing lib code and customize as you want. like you can block those email, URL, phone no etc which you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Zbar Code Scanner`  for `Android/ios` and customize it the way you want it